# Threading data on TimeSeries

Tags: data, time-series, data-structures

Say I have two TimeSeries:

```
x = TimeSeries[{2, 4, 1, 10}, {{1, 2, 4, 5}}]
y = TimeSeries[{6, 2, 6, 3, 9}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]
```

x has a value at times: 1,2,4,5

y has a value at times: 1,2,3,4,5

I would like to build a list of pairs {$x_i$, $y_i$} which would not include missing elements (in this case element x element at time 3 is missing)

The desired result would be:

```
{{2,6}, {4,2}, {1,3}, {10,9}}
```

I have a feeling that this should be simple and perhaps I'm not using right tools.

Answer (score 7):

One possible solution is to use [`TimeSeriesResample`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html?q=TimeSeriesResample):

```
td = TimeSeriesResample[TemporalData[{x, y}], "Intersection"];
```

Using `"Intersection"` instructs `TimeSeriesResample` to use *only* common timestamps for all paths.

Then

```
td["Paths"] // (Part[#, All, All, -1] &) /* Transpose
```

evaluates to

> ```
> {{2, 6}, {4, 2}, {1, 3}, {10, 9}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

`TimeSeriesThread` is probably the tool for the job when you specify the right options:

```
x = TimeSeries[{2, 4, 1, 10}, {{1, 2, 4, 5}}];
y = TimeSeries[{6, 2, 6, 3, 9}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}];
DeleteMissing[
 TimeSeriesThread[Identity, {x, y}, ResamplingMethod -> None]["Values"],
 1, 1
]
```

> {{2, 6}, {4, 2}, {1, 3}, {10, 9}}

Answer (score 5):

One way you can do this is by combining the two `TimeSeries` into `TemporalData` with no resampling:

```
x = TimeSeries[{2, 4, 1, 10}, {{1, 2, 4, 5}}]
y = TimeSeries[{6, 2, 6, 3, 9}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]

td = TemporalData[{x, y}, ResamplingMethod -> None]
```

Then, we can get the "Slices" for the range of times:

```
td["SliceData", Range[5]]
```

> `{{2, 4, Missing[], 1, 10}, {6, 2, 6, 3, 9}}`

And we can `Transpose` that to get pairs:

```
Transpose@td["SliceData", Range[5]]
```

> `{{2, 6}, {4, 2}, {Missing[], 6}, {1, 3}, {10, 9}}`

and finally, drop all pairs that contain `Missing` using `DeleteMissing`'s second and third argument:

```
DeleteMissing[Transpose@td["SliceData", Range[5]], 1, 1]
```

> `{{2, 6}, {4, 2}, {1, 3}, {10, 9}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply normalize the data (`x` and `y`), convert it to an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) and later [`Merge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html) it.

```
data = {<|Rule @@@ Normal[x]|>, <|Rule @@@ Normal[y]|>};
Merge[
      data, 
      If[Length[#] == 2, #, Nothing] &
    ] // Values
```

> {{2, 6}, {4, 2}, {1, 3}, {10, 9}}